# How to specify the property within an embedded property?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I want to query with the properties within an embedded type:

```
@Embeddable
class MCValue {
    Currency currency;
    BigDecimal value;
}

@Entity
class Record {
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "currency", column = @Column(name = "price_cc")), 
        @AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "price")) })
    MCValue price;
}
```

However, in the criteria query, I don't know how to specify them, or should it even be supported?

I've tried but none of these succeeded:

```
Projections.groupProperty("price_cc")
Projections.groupProperty("price.currency")
Projections.sum("price")
Projections.sum("price.value")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is indeed `price.currency` and `price.value`. Hibernate queries are always written in termes of objects and their fields, and never in terms of database columns.

If it doesn't work, it means that you have some other error in your code. Include the complete code and the exception stack trace.

Comment: Yes, the syntax is correct, it's my mistake. But I think the Hibernate manual should mention this usage of embedded types, otherwise I don't know whether it is supported.

Comment: It does: see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-select: "Queries can return properties of any value type including properties of component type: [...]". See also http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-grouping : "A query that returns aggregate values can be grouped by any property of a returned class or components"